# Left and Right Cosets using Cayley table

Tags: abstract-algebra

[Cayley Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iesN4.png)

I'm trying to figure out how to generate left and right cosets of H in G with G = {e, a, b, c} and we let H = [a] (a is supposed to be in <>).

I know that: Given G is a group, with a in G and H is a subset a G then

aH = { ah| h in H) = The left coset of H in G containing a

Ha = { ha| h in H) = The right coset of H in G containing a

how do I apply that to the cayley table?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you must know that every group upto order 5 is abelian. And so, the left cosets and right cosets are same. Do this help ?

Comment: yes that does help.